# I don't know how to save Login Information of user on iPhone

Tags: iphone, authentication

I am making app about google documents. but I don't know **How to save Login Information**

Document Folder ? Cache Folder ? Where save Login Information ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is to use [the keychain.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html)

There's example code at [the Apple site](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GenericKeychain/index.html) or Buzz Anderson has some great code at [his site](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code)

Alternatively you could use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but that's less secure. The keychain is encrypted, user defaults are not (unless you encrypt before insertion but that's extra work)